# Bash completion function: limit matches via glob

Tags: bash, bash-completion

A Bash completion function that uses `compgen` can work with the current partially-complete word. How can I restrict matches to those which match a specific file glob?

The `-G 'fooglob'` option does not do this; it *ignores* the current word and just unconditionally matches the glob.

What I want is:

```bash
compgen -A file -FOO '*.yaml' -- "$cur"
```

and have the generated options only those that match *both* the current word *and* the specified glob. So what is that hypothetical `-FOO` option?

(Note that this is a question specifically about writing functions in the Bash programming language, which is why it's appropriate on StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
compgen -A file -X '!*.yaml' -- "$cur"
```

---

According to the Bash reference manual section on [Programmable Completion Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins):

> complete
>   […]
>
> -X *filterpat*
>
> *filterpat* is a pattern as used for filename expansion.
>     It is applied to the list of possible completions generated by the preceding
>     options  and  arguments,  and each completion matching *filterpat*
>     is removed from the list.  A leading `!` in *filterpat* negates the pattern;
>     in this case, any completion not matching *filterpat* is removed.

(The `compgen` command honours most of the options to `complete`, including the one documented above.)